# How can I change the images only from css?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqQbrG)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div id="cf2" class="shadow">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://assets.sport.ro/assets/protv/2014/12/31/image_galleries/40908/cele-mai-frumoase-peisaje-din-lume-locurile-pe-care-trebuie-sa-le-vizitezi_1_size19.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="http://assets.sport.ro/assets/protv/2014/12/31/image_galleries/40908/cele-mai-frumoase-peisaje-din-lume-locurile-pe-care-trebuie-sa-le-vizitezi.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
img{
  width:300px;
}
@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

#cf3 img.top {
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

I want to exchange images between them using keyframes.

I tried to reproduce one of the examples [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) but something does not work.

Can you tell me what I'm not doing right?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are accessing wrong id in css

```css
img{
  width:300px;
  /* added this position to make images overlap */
  position: absolute; 
}
@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

/* here your name of id was wrong */
#cf2 img.top {
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf2" class="shadow">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://assets.sport.ro/assets/protv/2014/12/31/image_galleries/40908/cele-mai-frumoase-peisaje-din-lume-locurile-pe-care-trebuie-sa-le-vizitezi_1_size19.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="http://assets.sport.ro/assets/protv/2014/12/31/image_galleries/40908/cele-mai-frumoase-peisaje-din-lume-locurile-pe-care-trebuie-sa-le-vizitezi.jpg" />
</div>
```